# Looking for a way to have class method that is aware of which subclass called it

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm using python 2.7.

I have 2 classes:

```
class Jambi(Model):
    def do_something(self):
        print # string of class that called `do_something`.

class User(Jambi):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

From within the `do_something` method on the `Jambi` object, I would like to know which subclass is calling `do_something`.  So if an instance of the `User` class calls `do_something`, the `do_something` method prints out the string representation of the class.

How can I print out this information from within `do_something`?

I have been googling around but I think I have some terminology mixed up or something because I have not found the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print out the type of the original object with `print(type(self))`

```
class Jambi(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print(type(self))

class User(Jambi):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

x = User()

x.do_something()
```

Or (in python 3) use the `.__qualname__` of that type to get just the detailed name.  In both versions you can use the `__name__` to get just the class name.

Comment: Ok, this was a p.i.c.n.i.c.. I was actually instantiating the Jambi class and that is why I wasn't seeing the results I expected when using type(self) or self.__class__.  Boy has it been a long day.  Thanks!

Comment: haha, if you tried to include a mcve you probably would have noticed before posting.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, you can use `type(self)`.  You can also use `self.__class__`.  The former is nicer, but it doesn't work if your class does not inherit from `object` (just in Python 2 because in Python 3, all classes inherit from `object`).  If you want to get the name of a class, use `.__name__`.  Therefore, it would be `type(self).__name__` or `self.__class__.__name__`.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print type(self), type(self).__name__
...         print self.__class__, self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> MyClass()
<type 'instance'> instance
__main__.MyClass MyClass
>>> class MyClass2(MyClass):
...     pass
...
>>> MyClass2()
<type 'instance'> instance
__main__.MyClass2 MyClass2
>>> class MyClass3(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print type(self), type(self).__name__
...         print self.__class__, self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> MyClass3()
<class '__main__.MyClass3'> MyClass3
<class '__main__.MyClass3'> MyClass3
>>> class MyClass4(MyClass3):
...     pass
... 
>>> MyClass4()
<class '__main__.MyClass4'> MyClass4
<class '__main__.MyClass4'> MyClass4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `__class__.__name__` on the instance:

```
class Jambi():
    def do_something(self):
        print self.__class__.__name__
```

That will give you the class name of the instance:

```
In [1]: class Jambi():
   ...:     def do_something(self):
   ...:             print self.__class__.__name__
   ...:         

In [2]: class User(Jambi):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     
In [3]: u = User()

In [4]: u.do_something()
User
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` represents the instance that called the method so `type(self)` or `self.__class__` should do the trick.